# FormClosing event handled when button clicked

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've got a form with some button,textboxs and a datagrid. I want to execute some code when the user clicks on close button. When the user click the close button the code below executes, so it runs correctly.

The problem start when a button is clicked and after the code inside the sub that captures the "buttonclicked" event isexecuted it goes to the sub that captures the "formclosing" event and i don't know why this was happening, other times i used the formclosing events and it runs correctly.

FormClosing sub:

```
    Private Sub FRM_Ver_Maq_Closing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

        Dim buit As Boolean = False

        For pos As Byte = 0 To DG_Verificacions.VisibleRowCount - 1

            If DG_Verificacions(pos, 8) = 0 Then
                buit = True
            End If
        Next

        If buit Then
            Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Has deixat algunes característiques sense entrar el resultat, estàs segur de que vols sortir?", "Atenció!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            If result = DialogResult.No Then
                e.Cancel = True
            ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
                e.Cancel = False
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

Button clicked sub:

```
    Private Sub BTN_NovaValidacio_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTN_NovaValidacio.Click

        Dim id As Integer
        Dim Pos As Short

        Pos = DG_Verificacions.CurrentRowIndex

        Comu.MySelection.CommandText = "SELECT NVL (MAX (ID), 0) + 1 FROM i_cal_vermaq WHERE codmaq = '" & DG_Verificacions(Pos, 2) & "'"
        id = Comu.MySelection.ExecuteScalar()

        LBL_Id.Text = id

        Omplir_DG_Verificacions()

    End Sub
```

See if anyone can help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you `BTN_NovaValidacio` has its `DialogResult` property set.

Comment: Yes it's this, thank you very much!!!